# Lightbox Display Loading Box at End of Page

Tags: lightbox

I'm using Lightbox for the first time, and it's working for my images. However, for some reason, I get a strange box at the end of my page that shows the loading icon, even though there shouldn't be an image there.

The image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoEeX.png

Upon inspecting the element, I get the following HTML code.

```
<div id="lightbox"><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image"><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev"></a><a class="lb-next"></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"><img src="/z/styles/images/loading.gif"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div><div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"><img src="/z/styles/images/close.png"></a></div></div></div></div>
```

The strange part about this code is that I didn't make that div, it seems to have just been inserted by the script. Does anyone know what this might be and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could easily be a problem with your css or script path.

If you look at the lightbox2 demo it displays that loading page you see and then removes it to display the loaded image. When either the javascript or stylesheets are not correctly linked it will not work properly.

Lightbox2 site: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

You can try using (in chrome, for firefox there's firebug) right-click inspect element, go to the resources tab and expand the frames boxes until you see all the images, scripts and style sheets in a list. It'll let you know if one of them can't be found.

Comment: Thanks. My issue was that I had one php file including another, and I had linked lightbox.js in both the top file and the included one. Fixed the issue by removing it from the included file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I integrated Lightbox with an MVC site. The issue was I had referred both `lightbox.js` and `lightbox.min.js` files. I fixed the issue by removing one reference.

Comment: Yeah I had the same by accidentally referencing lightbox.js twice!